# MEANJS server controller call from Angular service

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, meanjs

There are three Models in the picture User, UserDetails, Order. I want to fetch userDetails based upon the userId in Order.

Model UserDetails:  [image]

Model Order:
[image]

I've removed few properties in the pic to make it short.

**I've a remote method on server controller**

```
exports.userdetailByUserID = function(req, res,id) {
//var userId = new ObjectId(id);
Userdetail.find({ user : req.params['userId'] }).exec(function(err,     userdetail) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        if (! userdetail) return next(new Error('Failed to load Userdetail ' + id));
        req.userdetail = userdetail ;
        console.log(userdetail);
    });
};
```

**server route defined as**

```
 app.route('/orders/getUserDetails/:userId').get(orders.userdetailByUserID);
```

**If I make a call on browser directly like this:**

```
http://localhost:3000/orders/getuserdetails/561ac35ce8436dc41b37011d
```

**I get the desired output. thats the userdetails of the userId for the order. 
But I'm not sure how to make a call from client service. 
I'm doing something like this below:**

```
.factory('GetUserDetails', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
    var resource;
    resource=$resource('/orders/userdetails/:userId',{userId:  '@userId'},{
        getUserDetail:{
            method:'GET',
            isArray:true
        }
    });
        return resource;
    }]);
```

and in controller : I'm calling service like :

```
function loadUserDetails() {
    $scope.userDetails = GetUserDetails.getUserDetail({userId :userid}).$promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.userDetails = data;
    });
    }
```

Its not producing the desired result as this make calls to userdetails and fetch all the records but I only want a single record for the userId I input.

Comment: when you call the `GetUserDetails.getUserDetails(...)` function, in your network panel do you see the userId being inserted in the URL of the query?

Comment: I see in console following : GET /userdetails?userId=56135fe07938e5ec029f70b0 304 21207.463 ms - -

Comment: I see in Network and  console following : GET /userdetails?userId=56135fe07938e5ec029f70b0 304 21207.463 ms - -  but it should be  http://localhost:3000/orders/userdetails/56135fe07938e5ec029f70b0

Comment: That's odd, so the prefix of your URL is wrong, let me try and reproduce it myself (if you could provide a plunkr it would help)